# Check first character of each line for a specific value in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, char, character

I am reading in a text file that contains a specific format of numbers. I want to figure out if the first character of the line is a 6 or a 4 and store the entire line in an array for use later. So if the line starts with a six add the entire line into sixArray and if the line starts with a 4 add the entire line into fourArray.

How can I check the first character and then grab the remaining X characters on that line? Without replacing any of the data?

Comment: Nothing, I am not able to find anything about reading only the first character. I have a working comparison statement that I can use once I am able to read the first character of each line.

Comment: Look at the documentation for the Substring() method of the String object type.

Comment: I'm torn between String methods and Regular Expressions.  Lately I've been turning to Regex's every time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this would probably work.

```
$sixArray = @()
$fourArray = @()

$file = Get-Content .\ThisFile.txt
$file | foreach { 
    if ($_.StartsWith("6"))
    {
        $sixArray += $_
    }

    elseif($_.StartsWith("4"))
    {
        $fourArray += $_
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're running V4:

```
$fourArray,$sixArray = 
((get-content $file) -match '^4|6').where({$_.startswith('4')},'Split')
```

Comment: I don't know how this works, but it does, and it's beautiful.

Comment: @theMadTechnician http://learn-powershell.net/2013/11/26/checking-out-the-where-and-foreach-operators-in-powershell-v4/

Comment: This is beautiful and works but sadly is limited to V4. Most of my users will be using V2

Comment: Then one of the other posted solutions will probably be more appropriate. But it does make for a nice solution if you have the newer version :).  If it's a really large file, I'd opt for arraylists over arrays, tho.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
$Fours = @()
$Sixes = @()
GC $file|%{
    Switch($_){
        {$_.StartsWith("4")}{$Fours+=$_}
        {$_.StartsWith("6")}{$Sixes+=$_}
    }
}
```

Comment: Does StartsWith make a huge difference over .SubString?

Comment: Nope, and actually .Substring() is faster (well, 12 milliseconds over 200 entries faster, but still faster), but `.StartsWith("4")` just seems cleaner than `.Substring(0,1) -match "4"` to me.

Answer (score 0):

If it's me I'd just use a regex.

A pattern like this will catch everything you need.

```
`'^[4|6](?<Stuff>.*)$'`
```